# Sql Server: getting the names of the objects involved in errors

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

In order to help with debugging, I want to get the specific name of objects (like tables, constraints, indexes, etc.) which are involved when SQL Server raises an error.

How can this be done?

For example, I have an error 2627, which generates an error message like this: `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__uniquete__3213E83E532B218D'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.uniquetest'. The duplicate key value is (1).` I want to get the table name `dbo.uniquetest` and the constraint name `UQ__uniquete__3213E83E532B218D`. I can't see a way to get this from any SQL Client or even from the server itself.

Comment: Yea, that question answered it. Terrible title, though; couldn't find it in a search.